# Seeting up vscode for PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, visual-studio-code, pyspark

Recently i have install vscode and wanted develop PySpark application . Can anyone help me to add existing Pysprak jars to visual code ??? I have already install Spark on Windows and want to use those jars (dont want to install Pyspark again using PIP). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't add JARs to VSCode, you would define the Spark submit arguments in the Python code like so

```
import os 
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages ...' 

# your spark code
```

You can also install the `findspark` package which will locate your Spark installation directory

Comment: ok ..Thanks... This can be use as work around .. But is this not looks little wired than production standard code ?? I saw some places , people are adding few parameters in setting.json file to provide jars . Cant we do similar thing for Pyspark ?? I tried but not able to succed . may b something i am missing.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_working-with-jar-files

Comment: can i add folows in setting.json file of vscode.??.


"java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "D:\\Installation\\BigData\\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\\jars",
        "D:\\Installation\\BigData\\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\\python\\lib\\*.jars"
    ]
}

Comment: Is it ok lf i add like this ?



from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages  "D:\\Installation\\BigData\\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\\jars, "D:\\Installation\\BigData\\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\\python\\lib\\* .jars"'

Comment: You shouldn't add every jar, no. When you start a Spark job, it'll pick up all jars in the Spark installation directory. The packages argument is meant to be used for external libraries, and you're using a Python project, not Java, so I'm not sure how the Vscode json file will help/work with that

Comment: Hi . i tried your suggestion . But seems like my Spark application still not able to get the jars . So it is saying "Pyspark module is not found "  from line  
"from pyspark. .. . . . import SparkSession ". Can you suggest what i am doing wrong ??

Comment: Then you've not installed pyspark into that Python environment you're using. Has nothing to do with jars